# How to change the color of the very first React component frame

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was working on some kind of loading for my app and then I found out that there is a short while when the blank white page is displayed. I also checked the default React app and it happens too, however it does not happen for example here on Stack Overflow. It wouldn't be a problem, but I want to implement a dark mode and don't want my user to experience white flicker in the middle of dark UI.

[Here you can see what happens right before the render of default React app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQPmh.png)

I was able to change the color of the second frame (via body styles in index.html in React app), but can't do so with the very first one. Don't even know what to search for.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. We don't debug images.

Comment: I know, but it is something that happens even in the boilerplate React App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React takes a while to take control of the screen. For that, there is a white screen page. This screen can be styled in index.html before JavaScript is loaded, but for advanced structures you will need to prerender your pages at build time or per request on the server. [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) is an amazing React framework that you should take a look at.